# Bad Base-64 as response

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have created a share function using react-native-share for android where I convert the data to base64 and then share as follows

```
shareImage= (item) => {
  RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', `some url`+item._id)
    .then(resp => {
      console.log('response : ', typeof resp);
      console.log('fff', resp.data);
      let base64image = resp.data;
      share('data:image/png;base64,' + base64image);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      err && console.log(err);
    });

  share = base64image => {
    console.log('base64image : ', base64image);
    var shareOptions = {
      title:item.title,
      url: base64image,
      // message: 'https://somelink.com some message',
      subject: 'Subject'
    };

    Share.open(shareOptions)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        err && console.log(err);
      });
    }
  };
```

to share images and the data fetched from url, however when I run this I get an error as BAD BASE-64, my logs are:

```
 response :  object
 LOG  fff <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /homeundefined</pre>
</body>
</html>

 LOG  base64image :  data:image/png;base64,<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /homeundefined</pre>
</body>
</html>

 LOG  {"error": "bad base-64"}
```

Can anyone, please tell am where am going wrong?

Comment: Your `RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', `some url`+item._id)` item._id is undefined, is the so the response is incorrect?

Comment: Yes, I am not recieving a correct response  for item._id, however I have declared item globally and then calling the id parameter. @Michael

Comment: From log fff you can see the `resp.data` is not image base64 format, you should fix that first

Comment: I meant, i am getting image format, although I have mixed files that am fetching from the api, fff is showing the whole response for the item, and base64 format is showing jpeg @Michael